# Understanding a particular group/semigroup operation

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups, semigroups

Let $\odot$ be the binary operation defined by
$$ x\odot y := (x+y)+(x\cdot y)$$
where $+$ and $\cdot$ are the usual operations of addition and multiplication from whatever ring you're working with. It's straightforward to show that $\odot$ is both commutative and associative if $+$ and $\cdot$ are. Moreover, $0$ is an identity.

Naturally this then lead me to explore what would happen if we used this operation to create a semigroup structure on $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, where all of the arithmetic is carried out modular $n$. Here are a few of the semigroup tables for some small values of $n$:

$$n=4 \quad \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\hline
\odot & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} \\ \hline
 \mathbf{0} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{1} & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{2} & 2 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{3} & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3
\end{array} \quad\quad\quad n=5 \quad \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\hline
\odot & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} \\ \hline
 \mathbf{0} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{1} & 1 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{2} & 2 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{3} & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{4} & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
\end{array}$$

$$
n=6 \quad \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\hline
\odot & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5} \\ \hline
 \mathbf{0} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{1} & 1 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{2} & 2 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 5 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{3} & 3 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 5 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{4} & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{5} & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5
\end{array} \quad\quad\quad n=7 \quad \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\hline
\odot & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & \mathbf{4} & \mathbf{5} & \mathbf{6} \\ \hline
 \mathbf{0} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{1} & 1 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{2} & 2 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 6 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{3} & 3 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 6 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{4} & 4 & 2 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{5} & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\ \hline
 \mathbf{6} & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6
\end{array}
$$

It's straightforward to prove that $\odot$ always fails to be a group operation on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ because there is no inverse element for $n-1$. However, after investigating a number of tables I started to notice a few things, and made the following conjectures:

- When $n$ is prime, suddenly $\odot$ seems to become a group operation, although not on the enitre set. Rather, it seems to become a group action on the subset $\mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$.
- Also, the above condition seems to be necessary. That is, when $n$ is composite $\odot$ fails to be a group operation (again, missing inverses) on $\mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$.

I'm pretty lost when trying to prove these. Moreover, should these conjectures be true, I would love to know what finite groups these structures are representing. Does anyone have any suggestions? My algebra is quite rusty.

Comment: Have you tried $\, 1 + x\odot y = 1+ (x+y)+(x\cdot y) = (1+x)\cdot(1+y)?$

Comment: Don’t say “group action”; a group action is a function $G\times X\to X$ where $G$ is a group and $X$ is a set, such that $(gh)x = g(h(x))$ and $ex=x$ for all $x\in X$ and $g,h\in G$. You mean it fails to be a “group operation”.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we are working on $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Your conjectures are:

1. If $n$ is prime, then $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}_n\mid x\not\equiv -1\pmod{n}\}$ is a group under $\odot$.
2. If $n$ is not prime, then $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}_n\mid x\not\equiv -1\pmod{n}\}$ is not a group under $\odot$.

(Note that $-1$ is a zero in the corresponding semigroup, since $x\odot(-1) = x-1 + x(-1) = -1$; hence you definitely need to exclude that element).

Your conjecture is indeed true.

You already know that $\odot$ is commutative and associative, so it’s just a matter of determining when do elements have inverses.

Suppose first that $n$ is prime, and let $x$, $0 < x <n-1$. You are looking for $y$ such that $x+y+xy = 0$; this is equivalent to $y(1+x)\equiv x \pmod{n}$. Since $x\not\equiv -1\pmod{n}$, then $x+1\not\equiv 0\pmod{n}$, so it has a multiplicative inverse $z$ modulo $n$. Thus, $y \equiv xz\pmod{n}$ will be an inverse for $x$. Thus, in this case you get a group.

Suppose next that $n$ is not a prime, and let $d$ be a proper divisor of $n$, so that $1 < d < n - 1$. Let $x=d-1$. Then as above, an inverse $y$ for $x$ would have to satisfy $y(x+1)\equiv x\pmod{n}$, or $yd\equiv d-1\pmod{n}$. Since $d$ divides $n$, this implies $yd\equiv d-1\pmod{d}$, which requires $-1\equiv 0\pmod{d}$, which is only possible if $d=1$, which cannot hold. Thus, $x$ does not have a multiplicative inverse, and so what you have is not a group.

Now as to the structure, you are getting cyclic groups so far, generated by $2$ in both cases. I’d have to think about it to see if this is indeed the case.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'd love to know if you figure out how to prove that it is always the cyclic group generated by 2. I'll play around with it a bit myself, as well.

Comment: By the way, your operation is sometimes known as the “circle operation” or “circle compostion”, though it is sometimes defined as $(x,y)\mapsto x+y-xy$. It’s defined for all (commutative?) rings, and you can look at the set of elements with inverses, which defines what is sometimes called the “circle group” of the ring.  It is known that if $R$ is a ring, then the operation defines a group on the Jacobson radical of the ring, which is the intersection of all maximal ideals of the ring (though it can sometimes be extended).

Comment: That is very interesting. Thank you for sharing that. I stumbled upon this idea while trying to teach the concepts of commutativity and associativity to 9th grade algebra students. I was looking to cook up a non-trivial example of an operation that had both properties, but acted on the kinds of objects (numbers, as opposed to matrices) they had already seen. If you can think of an example of an operation on Reals that is only associative, but not commutative, I'd love to see that as well! (I can only think of matrix multiplication...)